# huge size of shadow cache in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am facing performance issue(95-100% cpu and ram usage) in visual studio 2013.
 Recently I noticed that size of shadowcache

> (C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\Designer\ShadowCache)

is more than 10 gb. I think visual studio is slowing down because of high hd read/writes operations. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: Do you edit XAML by any chance?

Comment: yeah.I am working on wpf application and using resharper, devexpress, svn and teamcity pluggins.

Comment: Then it'll be an [unfixed bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807676/vs2013-shadowcache-overflowing-to-massive-sizes-for-xaml-editing-users) that you're experencing, I'll add that as an answer. By any chance if you have time could you install Visual Studio 2015 and see if you're still experiencing the bug?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're experiencing a widely-documented [bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807676/vs2013-shadowcache-overflowing-to-massive-sizes-for-xaml-editing-users) with Visual Studio 2013, when executing one of the following activities:

> 1. XAML editing without ReSharper
> 2. XAML editing with ReSharper
> 3. C# and F# editing without ReSharper
> 4. C# editing with ReSharper

There doesn't seem to be any official fix for this yet (the bug report on Microsoft Connect is actually closed for some unknown reason), but a temporary fix seems to be:

> delete the entire shadow cache

This bug only seems to occur with Visual Studio 2013, so a fix could be to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 (*which isn't the best fix, especially for a developer team or studio*), or downgrade to an earlier version (again, not the best fix due to compatibility with projects).

Comment: Thanks for your solution, i have deleted the mentioned shadow cache folder, problem solved.

Comment: Is there any script for deleting shadow cache frequently without closing visual studio.Generally most of the folders are not allowed to delete when VS is open.

Comment: This is still happening with Visual Studio 2022! My Designer cache is 131GB!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is occursin Visual studio 2017. One have to delete the folder before the designer problem disappear.